# Include a model in the through clause Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model A which has a many to many link with a model B, C presents the association model and it has a one to many link with model D.

the associations are below:

```
A.belongsToMany(B, { through: C}); 
B.belongsToMany(A, { through: C});
C.belongsTo(D, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
```

I want to retrieve Data from Table A which are linked to Table B and to get the corresponding Data from Table D. Means something like this :

```
A.findAll({ 
   include : [ {   model: B, 
                   through : { model : C, include: [{ model : D }]  } 
             } ] 
})
```

I have tried to do it otherwise but it doesn't work too:

```
C.findAll({ 
     include: [ { 
                  { model : A, include: [{ model : B}] }, 
                  { model : D}
              } ]
})
```

does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do so is the super many to many relationship and you can find more details in the documentation : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html#the-best-of-both-worlds--the-super-many-to-many-relationship